# Add swipe gesture recogniser to uilabel (swift)

Tags: swift, uigesturerecognizer

```
        let urgencyLabel = UILabel(frame:CGRectMake(renderWidth,0,80,60))
        urgencyLabel.text = "Urgency"
        view.addSubview(urgencyLabel)
```

How can i add a swipe left gesture recogniser to uilabel instead of whole view controller?

Answer (score 1):

Here is one possible solution:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    let urgencyLabel = UILabel(frame:CGRectMake(100,100,80,60))
    urgencyLabel.text = "Urgency"
    view.addSubview(urgencyLabel)
    urgencyLabel.userInteractionEnabled = true


    let myRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "swipeLeftFunc:")
    myRecognizer.direction = [.Left]

    urgencyLabel.addGestureRecognizer(myRecognizer)

}



func swipeLeftFunc(sender: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {

        print("Swipe left")

}
```

It is important to enable user interaction using:

```
urgencyLabel.userInteractionEnabled = true
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a swipe gesture in your viewController 's viewDidLoad method:

```
override func viewDidLoad(){
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let swipeLeft = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(swipedToLeft))
    swipeLeft.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Left

    urgencyLabel.addGestureRecognizer(swipeLeft)
}

//Implement the action for the gesture

func swipedToLeft() {
    //Do stuff when swiping left is recognised
}
```

Also you can add gesture recognisers from within Storyboard/xib as well. Follow this tutorial for more information -

https://www.raywenderlich.com/76020/using-uigesturerecognizer-with-swift-tutorial

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    let swipeLeft = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.swipedLeft))
    swipeLeft.direction = .Left
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeLeft)

}
func swipedLeft()
{
    print("swiped left")
}
```